# How to return an array of unknown size from a JNI C function to Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, c, matlab, java-native-interface

I've converted a MATLAB script to C using MATLAB Coder. The script takes a video in uint8 format as an input, performs an object detection task using a customized YOLOv4 DL network to identify objects of interest and creates a new uint8 array (video) cropped within the object boundaries (see code below):

```
function [I] = Android3(Vrecorded)

%#codegen
% Loads and created pretrained YOLO v4 DL NW detector customized 
% to detect LED array.

detector = coder.loadDeepLearningNetwork("trainedDetector_23022023.mat");

% Read all frames as grayscale images
frames = reshape(Vrecorded(:,:,1,:), size(Vrecorded,1), size(Vrecorded,2), []);

% extrai o número de quadros do vídeo capturado (NoF - Number of Frames)
NoF = size(frames,3);

%Detect objects in an unknown image / video by using the pretrained YOLO v4
FrameForDetection = zeros(size(Vrecorded,1),size(Vrecorded,2),3);
FrameForDetection(:,:,:) = Vrecorded(:,:,:,1);

%object detector
[bboxes,~,~] = detect(detector,FrameForDetection);

% This cell contains the cropped frames containing RoI after YOLO v4 object
% detection algoritm process the frames
croppedFrameVectors = cell(1,1);

sizes = imcrop(frames(:,:,1),bboxes(1,:));

croppedFrames = zeros(size(sizes,1),size(sizes,2),NoF);

for n = 1:1
    croppedFrameVectors{n} = rand(0,0,0);
    for k = 1:NoF
        % crops the frames in each detected object according to bounding
        % boxes results captured on the first frame
        croppedFrames(:,:,k) = imcrop(frames(:,:,k),bboxes(1,:));
    end
    % Insert the cropped frames with bounding boxes within a cell to allow
    % multiple cropped objects within the same variable
    croppedFrameVectors{n} = croppedFrames;
    % Erase variable to crop another object due to bbox different
    % dimensions from one object to another (widht x height)
end

I = croppedFrameVectors{1};
```

Where Vrecorded is a video matriz of size 240x320xF, and F vary depending on the input video.

After converting it to C and trying to adjust it to JNI syntax, this is what I have so far:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Include files */
#include "main.h"
#include "Android3.h"
#include "Android3_emxAPI.h"
#include "Android3_terminate.h"
#include "Android3_types.h"
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include <android/log.h>


JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_occ_MainActivity_teste(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray Vrecorded) {
    emxArray_real_T *b_I;
    //emxArray_uint8_T *Vrecorded;

    // Call the entry-point function 'Android3'
    emxInitArray_real_T(&b_I, 3);
    Android3(Vrecorded, b_I);

    // Clean up memory
    emxDestroyArray_uint8_T(Vrecorded);
    emxDestroyArray_real_T(b_I);
}
```

Where Android3() is the function which performs the image processing from the MATLAB code. My Java Main application is:

```
package com.example.occ;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.occ.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'occ' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("occ");
    }

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        byte[] c = new MainActivity().teste(I);
        System.out.println("Value of matrix B is: " + Arrays.toString(c));

    }

    public native byte[] teste(byte[] I);
}
```

I have 2 questions so far:

1. Does my logic to pass the matrix Vrecorded (which is uint8 format) to the JNI function is correct (using byteArray[]). This matrix has 3 dimensions;
2. How do I return matrix 'I' to Java so it can be displayed on screen **if I don't know its size before compile runtime?**

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how any of this can work.
A java `byte[]` is an object that represents a **one-dimensional** array. On the JNI side this is an opaque `jbyteArray` object.
By "opaque" I mean that you cannot use this value by itself, you must use JNI functions like `GetByteArryaElements` to get a pointer to (a copy of) the actual byte array.
Yet your Matlab code treats it as a four-dimensional array.

A three-dimensional array `arr` would be a `byte[][][]`, for example. On the JNI side this is an opaque `jobjectArray` where the types of the layers are, in order:

- `arr` has type `byte[][][]` and JNI type `jobjectArray`
- `arr[x]` has type `byte[][]` and JNI type `jobjectArray`
- `arr[x][y]` has type `byte[]` and JNI type `jbyteArray`

So on the input side there are a number of  options:

- you either get your video as a flat `byte[]`, in which case you need to use the Matlab emx API to unpack it as a four-dimensional vector. This requires extracting the dimensions of each layer (or just "knowing" them).
- if it is truly a deeply nested array, you have to assemble the Matlab input array layer by layer. This will be deeply painful and very heavy on the garbage collector.

On the output side you have the reverse problem: do you represent it as a flat one-dimensional array, the fully three-dimensional (if I read your Matlab code correctly) array, or something inbetween? In my opinion the most natural way is to create a small helper class `Rect` that decorates a `byte[]` with width and height and then return a `Rect[][]`, where you have one `Rect[]` per input frame.

Finally, if performance is at all in the picture you will want to look at direct byte buffers, which are just chunks of native memory you can pass from Java to native code without copying.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you'll have to build a java array.  I think you should know the array size before returning the array back to java.  Look in the JNI documentation how to create a Java array of one of the basic types of Java.

How then is java to be capable to determine the array size?  Java arrays are objects, not as simple as arrays in C (which comprise just the plain array elements, one after the other) an array has an immutable `length` element and the array elements stored in its instance.  Just dig in JNDI documentation to get how to create a java array from the C helpers library.